# How much bitcoin debit card really cost?

Tags: debitcard

Just read this [article](https://www.weusecoins.com/bitcoin-debit-cards/) about Bitcoin debit cards. Two interesting statements I noticed:

- customers are not required to complete ID verification provided if they are happy to stay within the lower debit card limits
- there is also no loading fee

Guess when using in a supermarket, coins are sold on the fly on an online bitcoin stock exchange. Can not believe there is no service fee for transaction. Is it any hidden cost above 15 something dollar?

What if I register myself as "Mickey Mouse"? Will they approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Xapo is one of the cards that enable you to convert BTC in fiat currency, in the format of a credit card, this is their fee list:

https://support.xapo.com/what-fees-are-associated-with-the-xapo-debit-card

Hope it helps!

Cheers

Comment: 3% i see, not much